# jQuery unexpected token error =

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an `"unexpected token ="` on the function `toggleNav = function(evt){` line of the code sample below. I've went through a number of similar posts, but can't seem to see why it's throwing the error.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {

     $("#nav > li > a").on("click", toggleNav);

    function toggleNav = function(evt){
    var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $("#nav").removeClass("btn1 btn2 btn3 btn4 btn5 btn6 btn7").addClass(clicked);
    evt.preventDefault();
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Well, if you know the syntax it seems obvious where the error is... Check your code here http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: This ain't java you know. You cannot give type definition for a variable. i.e., its `var x = 1` not `int x = 1`.

Comment: @elclanrs Thank you! Normally our other developer does the jQuery work so I'm still getting the basics down. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
var toggleNav = function(evt){
    var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $("#nav").removeClass("btn1 btn2 btn3 btn4 btn5 btn6 btn7").addClass('clicked');
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

or you can directly call like

```
function toggleNav (evt) {
    var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $("#nav").removeClass("btn1 btn2 btn3 btn4 btn5 btn6 btn7").addClass('clicked');
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

And also put clicked in quotes because it is an class name

Answer (score 2):

You should just replace your `function toggleNav` with `var toggleNav`, and it should be ok.

Or you could also just remove that anonymous function, and do this way :

```
function toggleNav (evt) {
    var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $("#nav").removeClass("btn1 btn2 btn3 btn4 btn5 btn6 btn7").addClass(clicked);
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks more promising

```
$(function($) {
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $("#nav").removeClass("btn1 btn2 btn3 btn4 btn5 btn6 btn7").addClass(clicked);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax problem, you're using the function keyword twice there. Choose which way you want to use it. You can do either.